# How to set Gnome log-in screen to X11 (instead of wayland)

Tags: x11, gnome, wayland

How do I set the Gnome log-in screen to be X11 instead of Wayland?

When docked (into USB-C dock) and in Wayland, the computer hard freezes and the power button has to be held to shut it off.  This isn't an issue on X11, so I have to undock, log in choosing X11 and then re-dock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent a long time looking, only to find the answer a short time after posting a question.

in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
there is the following:

```
[daemon]
\# Uncoment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
WaylandEnable=false
```